# Where does optical character recognition (OCR) fall on the scale of problem difficulty?

Tags: complexity-theory, ocr, np-complete

How hard is Optical Character Recognition (OCR), formally? Let's assume an error tolerance comparable to a human (which is, I believe, around 98%).

In other words, where would it fit in the P/NP scale of problem complexity and intractability?

Or would it fit on that scale? Just what kind of problem is it?

I'm not terribly familiar with the formal definition of problem complexity. I'm just curious.

Comment: The difficulty of OCR depends very much on your acceptable error rate.

Comment: Let's shoot the moon: 98% (which I think is comparable to a human).

Comment: Also going to depend rather a lot on the quality of the input. Is the input device able to maintain high contrast, and low noise over the whole field? Is the source the free of blotch, doodles, dust, drink rings and other non-content marks? Are the characters in question consistent in form and size? Are their any ambiguities in the formation of the characters (i.e. can I distinguish a capital 'i' from a lower case 'l' from a one and a zero from a capital "o" or not)? And all that comes before you even start processing...

Comment: I suppose P/NP is about formally definable problems, whereas OCR is poorly defined by definition. So what kind of problem would it be? (I've updated the question to reflect this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in order to rate a problem in a computability scale you need to know what kind of computation model you are using. The problem as defined is not computable by any machine.

So I guess your question resembles asking how hard it is for a person to do complex calculations.

You can think of it this way, the human brain is by definition non deterministic moreover you can't exactly rate it as a computing model since it's not exactly measurable how many actions a human does when thinking of a problem. It's not discrete procedure.